# Bootstrap4: Multi-image Carousel

Tags: slider, carousel, bootstrap-4

i've been using this version of a multi image carousel on Bootstrap 4 but i can't figure out how to make it show 4 images instead of 3 .
the Code : https://www.codeply.com/go/s3I9ivCBYH/multi-carousel-single-slide-bootstrap-4

Comment: Have you made an attempt to figure out how the Codeply snippet works?

Comment: Maybe this solution helps you to fix your issues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77640427/how-to-create-an-infinity-multi-item-image-carousel-touch-and-all-plain-vani/77640428#77640428

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Bootstrap uses cols which are used to divide the page into 12 equal parts.  So, you first need to change the slide divs to be col-md-3 instead of 4, this makes each one 25% (3/12) width instead of 33.33 (4/12):

class="carousel-item **col-md-4** active"

-to-

class="carousel-item **col-md-3** active"

Next change by adding another ".carousel-item":

```
/* show 3 items */
.carousel-inner .active,
.carousel-inner .active + .carousel-item,
.carousel-inner .active + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
    display: block;
}
```

to

```
/* show 4 items */
.carousel-inner .active,
.carousel-inner .active + .carousel-item,
.carousel-inner .active + .carousel-item + .carousel-item,
.carousel-inner .active + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
    display: block;
}
```

and finally make one more of the slides visible here by adding another ".carousel-item":

```
/*make 4 slides visible*/
.carousel-inner .active.carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: -33.3333%;
        z-index: -1;
        display: block;
        visibility: visible;
    }
```